# Problems with creating ZIP file in c#

Tags: c#, zip, sharpziplib

I am trying to create zip file by this code, but nothing works, the constractor of ZipFile doesnt get 
**()** only overloading with arguments, and i don't have the `SAVE` method? 
**Whats wrong?**

```
   using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            zip.AddEntry("C://inetpub//wwwroot//Files//Wireframes//" + url, zip.Name);
            zip.AddDirectory("C://inetpub//wwwroot//Files//Wireframes//" + url);
            zip.Save(downloadFileName);
        }
```

Comment: What zip library are you using?. The syntax seems to be from DotNetZip, but your tag indicates SharpZipLib.

Comment: Provide more info about DLL has been used in ur code.

Comment: I am using  `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip,ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib`

Comment: Take a look [here](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/SharpZipLib-Zip-Samples.ashx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To zip an entire directory with SharpZipLib you could try this method:

```
    private void ZipFolder(string folderName, string outputFile)
    { 
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderName);
        using (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(File.Create(outputFile)))
        {
            zos.SetLevel(9); // 9 = highest compression
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(file));
                entry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
                zos.PutNextEntry(entry);
                using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(file))
                {
                   int byteRead;
                   do
                   {
                        byteRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0,buffer.Length);
                        zos.Write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
                   }
                   while (byteRead > 0);
                }
            }
            zos.Finish();
            zos.Close();
        }
```

As you can see we have a really different code from you example.
As I have said in my comment above, your example seems to come from [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)
If you wish to use that library your code will be:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())                    
{                        
    zip.AddFile("C://inetpub//wwwroot//Files//Wireframes//" + url);
    zip.AddDirectory("C://inetpub//wwwroot//Files//Wireframes//" + url, "WireFrames");
    zip.Save(downloadFileName);                    
}
```

EDIT: To add al PNG files in a certain directory

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())                    
{                        
    string  filesPNG = Directory.GetFiles("C://inetpub//wwwroot//Files//Wireframes//" + url, "*.PNG);
    foreach(string file in filesPNG)
        zip.AddFile(file);
    zip.Save(downloadFileName);                    
}
```

Comment: The `private void ZipFolder()` don't work 100%, its only compressing the files in `folderName` without the sub directories.

Comment: Yes, this is an example taken from my own code where I have no need to zip subfolders.

Comment: In this same site there is an example of what you require. [Look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977668/sharpziplib-library-compress-a-folder-with-subfolders-with-high-level-compresion)

Comment: the problem is that i already using `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip` in something else in that program, if i delete it'the first example is working. But i need those namespace to other things... with the code for `SharpZipLib` i cant work...there's no option adding files

Comment: Do not use the root directory of C: drive. Try with a subfolder in which you have read/write permissions

Comment: OK, its working with another folder. How can i add a type of files like **all png** files?